# Why do iOS devices have both UDID and Serial Number?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uuid

Why do iOS devices have both the UDID and serial number?

Are they not the same; a number that uniquely identifies a device?

Comment: I assume you meant UDID, not UUID. A UDID has 40 hexadecimal digits, while a UUID has only 32. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No They are not same.

Serial number is Just a hardware device number that use for warranty claim of device. Its just like IEMI number of device

And UDID is hidden number to use for device testing its a unique key that is stored in apple database.

Comment: I think what OP meant is that since they both uniquely identify the phone why have both? It's like why have two primary keys on a table in a database.

Comment: Lie. They have two table for hardware and software no.
apple stores and services can access the details of device from Serial number. 

and apps work on UDID tabel model.